# Elements in array appear to be undefined, except when logging the whole array

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I've been working on some code with a collection of elements, while encountering some seemingly broken results. It appears to have the elements I need (as show on the output), but when I try to index one, it returns undefined.

```
var items = document.getElementsByClassName('side-item');
console.log(items);
console.log(items[0]);
console.log(items);
```

The resulting Console output:

[image: The resulting Console output]

I'd appreciate some help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the __code__ to your question, not as links to images somewhere off-site.

Comment: Most of the questions here contain *some code*, some of them work *on a collection* and all of them get some *interesting result / error*. Please describe *your* case, whats working, whats not, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392111/console-log-async-or-sync) by the way

Comment: No, I am not. I'm interested in why the element is undefined

Comment: What happens if you do `console.log(items.length);` first?

Comment: It returns 0, while the length should be 3 apparently

Comment: No, your `items` is empty. It appears to be filled later on because `console.log` is async in your browser, as explained in Jonas' link.

Comment: Ah I see. But why is it empty? It clearly has to be filled up by that call. Unless it is async, but I'm not sure why that would be. :I

Comment: Something else must be going on as [your code does not reproduce your problem](http://jsfiddle.net/ufh5ncmy/)

Comment: @RichárdNagy I'm guessing by the time your code runs, there are no elements with class `side-item` yet. They're probably created later.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot reproduce it in JSFiddle either. I copied the whole documents (html and css) there :I

Comment: Just curious, but what happens if you do console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('side-item')[0]) ?

Comment: Here's a reproducer: http://jsfiddle.net/smco60z9/1/